# dsPIC33E External Interrupts INT0,INT1,INT2 not firing

Tags: pic, embedded, interrupts

I have read every post I can find and still do not understand why external interrupts are not triggering, the following is my initialization, it is not clean, as I am in the process of trying everything I can think of to make this work.

To simplify the problem, consider only INT1.

Update: It appears the flag is getting triggered, but the ISR is never being executed. The flag is not being lowered

```
void __attribute__((__interrupt__, no_auto_psv)) _INT1Interrupt(void)
{
IFS1bits.INT1IF = 0;    //Clear the INT1 interrupt flag 
//U1TXREG='0';

m_Capture1 = 1;

}  




// Hall Sensor A                | Pin 31    RPI24       RA8

// Disable all other pin functionality.
TRISAbits.TRISA8 = 1 ;
//LATAbits.LATA8 = 0;
ODCAbits.ODCA8=0;
CNENAbits.CNIEA8=0;
CNPUAbits.CNPUA8=0;
CNPDAbits.CNPDA8=0;


//INTCON1bits.NSTDIS = 0; // interrupt nesting enabled.
//INTCON2bits.GIE = 1;    // Global Interrupt Enable.

INTCON2 = 0x0000;       // all interrupts on rising edge.       

// Reset Interrupt flags.
IFS0bits.INT0IF = 0;      //Reset INT0 interrupt flag 
IFS1bits.INT1IF = 0;    //Reset INT1 interrupt flag
IFS1bits.INT2IF = 0;    //Reset INT2 interrupt flag

INTCON2bits.INT0EP = 1 ;
INTCON2bits.INT1EP = 1 ;
INTCON2bits.INT2EP = 1 ;

// Enable Interrupts.
IEC0bits.INT0IE = 1;    // Enable INT0 Interrupt Service Routine.
IEC1bits.INT1IE = 1;    // Enable INT1 Interrupt Service Routine. 
IEC1bits.INT2IE = 1;    // Enable INT2 Interrupt Service Routine.

// Set Interrupt Priority.
//IPC5bits.INT1IP = 5;  // If all the IPC bits associated with
                        // an interrupt source are cleared, the interrupt 
                        // source is effectively disabled.
//IPC7bits.INT2IP = 2;  //set low priority
//IPC0bits.INT0IP = 2;  //set low priority
IPC5bits.INT1IP = 4;    /*set low priority*/


RPINR0bits.INT1R |= 24;//0x18; //001 1000;    // Set Hall A - RPI24/RA8 set                     INT1
RPINR1bits.INT2R |= 51;//0x33; //011 0011     // Set Hall B = RPI51/RC3 set INT2
// Hall C RP39/RB7 is INT0 (not mappable)
```

I have verified with 100% certainty that the voltage on the pin is changing from 0 to 3.3V. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Gary

Comment: Uncommenting:  INTCON2bits.GIE = 1;    // Global Interrupt Enable.

Comment: What is the exact chip model you have?

Comment: dsPIC33EP64MC206

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried uncommenting GIE

Answer (score 2):

At this point I feel fairly certain the problem was the line

```
 INTCON2 = 0x0000;
```

which effectively disabled bit 15 (global interrupt enable). The following is a working initialization function.

```
void BldcHallSensorInit( void )
{
// Hall Sensor A                | Pin 31    RPI24       RA8     INT2
// Hall Sensor B                | Pin 35    RPI51       RC3     INT1
// Hall Sensor C                | Pin 46    RP39        RB7     not mappable


TRISAbits.TRISA8 = 1 ;
TRISCbits.TRISC3 = 1 ;

RPINR0bits.INT1R = 51;  //001 1000;     // Set Hall B = RPI51/RC3 set INT2
RPINR1bits.INT2R = 24;  //011 0011      // Set Hall A - RPI24/RA8 set INT1 


//CORCONbits.IPL3 = 0;
//INTCON1bits.NSTDIS = 0; // interrupt nesting enabled.
//INTCON2bits.DISI = 0 ;
//INTCON2bits.SWTRAP = 0 ;

//INTCON2 = 0x0000;       // **erroneous line**       

// Reset Interrupt flags.
IFS0bits.INT0IF = 0;      //Reset INT1 interrupt flag 
IFS1bits.INT1IF = 0;    //Reset INT0 interrupt flag
IFS1bits.INT2IF = 0;    //Reset INT0 interrupt flag

// Interrupt edge polarity.
INTCON2bits.INT0EP = 1 ;
INTCON2bits.INT1EP = 1 ;
INTCON2bits.INT2EP = 1 ;

// Set Interrupt Priority.
IPC0bits.INT0IP = 1;    // set low priority.
IPC5bits.INT1IP = 1;    // set low priority.
IPC7bits.INT2IP = 1;    // set low priority.

// Enable Interrupts.
IEC0bits.INT0IE = 1;    // Enable INT0 Interrupt Service Routine.
IEC1bits.INT1IE = 1;    // Enable INT1 Interrupt Service Routine. 
IEC1bits.INT2IE = 1;    // Enable INT2 Interrupt Service Routine.

INTCON2bits.GIE = 1;    // Global Interrupt Enable. Order/placement of this
                        // line is important.
}
```